# Terminals that allow basic text editing of commands

Tags: macos, shell, unix, terminal, command-prompt

Is there a terminal application, particularly for Mac, that allows commands' text to be edited as in a word processor?

For example, in most terminals I know of, a user can't use ALT+BACKSPACE, can't remove more than one character at a time, can't cut, copy, or paste easily (if at all), can't use CMD+ARROW to go from one end of a long command to another quickly, etc., etc.

P.S. Is there a reason why editing text commands in a terminal is so (universally) cluncky?

Comment: Interesting that there have been a few down-votes but not no comments about their reasoning.

Answer (score 0):

In bash, you can

- move to the beginning of the line with Ctrl-A
- move to the end of the line with Ctrl-E
- delete a whole word with Esc and then Backspace

These and other routines come from Emacs. If you learn the basics of how to use that, then the shell will become very intuitive.

As for copy and paste, these are handled by the terminal rather than the shell. In many environments, just highlight the text with your mouse to copy, and then paste with either the middle button or right button of your mouse. In the Mac terminal, you can use the common copy and paste routines.